# how to reuse httpclient connection to get multiple small files

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using httpclient to download multiple small files from server continuously. So I want to reuse the httpclient connection to avoid costing a lot of time to allocate new connection.

And I already have some client code to try to reuse the connection, and set the idle timeout of existing connection to 3 minutes.

However the response from server always contains "Connection: close[\r][\n]", httpclient library releases the connection immediately after it meets such header.

How do I do to let httpclient to ignore the response from server, or which header I post could let server no longer return such closing header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you manage to *ignore* the `Connection: close` header, I don't think it would be a good idea "violate" the directive.

The RFC says [the following](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

> HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to
>   signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the
>   response. For example,
>
> ```
>    Connection: close
> ```
>
> in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the
>   connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' (section 8.1) after
>   the current request/response is complete.

Comment: Do you mean it's decided by server? No way to tune it in client side?

Comment: I don't think so (but this is far from my area really)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a keep-alive header to your HTTP requests.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/keepalive.html

Comment: Thanks for your link. However httpclient says it enables [connection persistence](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Connection_persistence) by default. The server still returns close directive.